# How to remove x-axis index from the tooltip/label

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

How to remove this value from bars (1,) I am using PrimeFaces and jqPlot would like to leave only the second value when hovering over the bar.

I already tried to search various information on the internet but found nothing exclusively about this customization. By the image below I better illustrate which value I want to remove from my bars in the chart.

https://ibb.co/8jSk4zP

```
function skinBarImpurezasMinerais() {
                this.cfg.shadow = false;
                this.cfg.title = '';
                //this.cfg.seriesColors = ['#e30910', '#FFC107'];
                this.cfg.grid = {
                    background: '#ffffff',
                    borderColor: '#ffffff',
                    gridLineColor: '#F5F5F5',
                    shadow: false
                };
                this.cfg.axesDefaults = {
                    borderWidth: 0.1,
                    borderColor: 'bdbdbd',
                    rendererOptions: {
                        textColor: '#666F77'
                    }
                };
                this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
                    shadow: false,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    stackSeries: true,
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    pointLabels: {show: true},
                    rendererOptions: {
                        varyBarColor: true,
                        barWidth: 50,
                    },
                    markerOptions: {
                        shadow: false,
                        size: 7,
                        style: 'circle'
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try searching for what is in the title now (slashes???)

Comment: Hello,
I think the title was edited by a translator when I added a tag.

Comment: Yes, by me... (You can see that here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57493566/revisions (click on the  'edited... x y ago link) ) The term 'slash' is totally wrong in this context, so if you cannot find anything using that term, that is not a surprise. That is why I changed it and mentioned it. Regarding the last part of the title, See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging,  And 'java' and 'javascript' should only be used if you have problems with the pure language. The fact that it is used here does not validate using the tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but with your term what I found was about another technology (Chart.js) and my problem is happening with technology (jqPlot).

But if you have a link that someone has solved my problem with, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Did you add jqplot in your search? That part (the tags) should be added by YOU: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=How+to+remove+x-axis+index+from+the+label+jqplot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jqplot tooltip on bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889464/jqplot-tooltip-on-bar-chart)

Comment: Yes,
I don't know if you understood my problem, look at this image maybe I really don't know how to do the research ..https://ibb.co/8jSk4zP

Comment: I understood perfectly... But If you use the wrong search terms ('value' and 'slash'). You won't find anything. Look at my searchterms in the link in the comment and the duplicate suggestion. I

Comment: Did it help? I'd like to know

Comment: Yes it helped me, I found the solution ..

Comment: Effectively your question is a duplicate, at least in a little more general way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution .. I had to add the block below

```
highlighter: { show: true, 
            showTooltip: true,      // show a tooltip with data point values.
            tooltipLocation: 'nw',  // location of tooltip: n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw.
            tooltipAxes: 'y',    // which axis values to display in the tooltip, x, y or both.
            lineWidthAdjust: 2.5   // pixels to add to the size line stroking the data point marker
            }
```

Comment: You are sooo welcome. Great incentive to help next time.